# Exchange server 2016 Content Filtering

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, spam

I have setup an exchange server on premise with at SMTP Relay on our VPS. It works very well, unfortunately I’m a little confused as to where I setup the various permissions for SPAM.
All my incoming email receives
The error that the other server returned was:

```
550 5.7.1 Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering.
```

The only way to get around it is to add the domain as an authoritative as an accepted domain. Which I assume must be the incorrect way to add them.
So please someone tell me where it is I can setup who can email in via my SMTP server?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: all incoming email gets  550 5.7.1 Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering. How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you explain this part further:  Exchange server on-premises, and a SMTP relay in a hosted service?  Please describe current or intended mail flow further. The message header for a failed message would help, please  feel free to obfuscate any domain-specific info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based solely on the information given, examine your Content Filter configuration in Exchange Powershell:

`Get-ContentFilter | Format-List`

Specific attributes to look at:

- `BypassedSenders`
- `ExternalMailEnabled`

Technet reference for Set-ContentFilter: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996791(v=exchg.160).aspx

Comment: I received back Enabled : True, there must be somewhere in the GUI or where Exchange can configure what emails can come in and what emails cannot?

Comment: If i wanted to allow Gmail to send emails to any users, what command would i use?